# Слово "год" при датах

Tags: даты

За 2015 и 2016 год мы не свернули ни одной программы, не был сокращен ни один работник.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, здесь нужно писать **годы** или **год**? или допустимы оба варианта?

Answer (score 4):

Два года, хоть и неполных, — годы. Число множественное. За 2015 и 2016 годы...

Answer (score 1):

*За 2015 и 2016 годы мы не свернули ни одной программы, не был сокращен ни один работник.*

Здесь имеется в виду общий период, сравнить:

[Декларация 3-НДФЛ за 2014 и 2015 годы | blanker.ru](http://blanker.ru/doc/deklaratsiya-3-ndfl-za-2014-god)

Answer (score 0):

Годы. А почему Год, если их два? По какой аналогии?

Comment: А почему заглавная?

Comment: Ошибся. Без задней мысли.